# Fundamental system of neighborhoods in topological space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\tau )$ be a topological space. Let $\mathfrak{B}_x$ be the fundamental system of neighborhoods of point $x\in X$. (a basis)

Is it true that, in general, any $B\in \mathfrak{B}_x$ is also a neighborhood of $x$ i.e does there exist $U\in\tau$ such that $x\in U\subset B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this holds by definition. A fundamental system of neighbourhoods consists of neighbourhoods in particular. You cannot really drop this easily, otherwise $\{\{x\}\}$ would be a fundamental system for $x$ all the time (and not only when $x$ is an isolated point, as the usual definition would imply).

There is also the notion of a local $\pi$-base ($\pi$ for p = pseudo, I think), which is a family $\mathcal{B}$ of non-empty open subsets of $X$ such that for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there exists some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $B \subseteq U$. Here we do not demand that the members of $\mathcal{B}$ are neighbourhoods of $x$ (or even contain $x$), but they do need to be non-empty and open, to avoid some trivialities.